# Formatting a json returned by a RESTful API

Tags: json, api, rest

If you were to call a restful api and were expecting to get a number (**not one item**) of items in json format. What would be the most correct format for an api to give this data to you:

a) `[{"a":1, "b":2}, {"a":3,"b":4}]` or

b) `{"element1":{"a":1, "b":2}, "element2":{"a":3, "b":4}}`

Or maybe there is a third way? Which one would be correct from the perspective of users working with this api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you were to call a restful api and were expecting to get a number (not one item) of items

Considering options A `[{"a":1, "b":2}, {"a":3,"b":4}]`

and B `{"element1":{"a":1, "b":2}, "element2":{"a":3, "b":4}}`

A is a list of items (note the `[ ]`). B is a single item (note the `{ }`).

B just so happens to be an item that has multiple sub items, but it is still 1 single item.

Therefore your answer would be to go with A, as A is a list of items.

Comment: I got confused because in my head json - corresponds to {} brackets only, and using [] - seemed a bit off for myself, but i just talked to a friend of mine who works with APIs a lot - he says that option A is fully legit. So, i all probably roll with the a one :)

Comment: @Dennis yes, json root object can be `[]` and `{}`, both are perfectly valid

Answer (score 0):

The 2 solutions are possible of course. But **solution 1** is more light (not need to create a "element1", "elementN" for each item) and it's provide a more generic structure (for REST API especially).
And, also it's depends how you want manipulating the data. With array (solution 1), it's maybe more easy.